# Find a $(a,b)$ satisfying $(A) \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}(a,b)=\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}(a,b)=0$

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

We have a function $z=z(x,y)$ satisfying
$$x^2+2y^2-2xy-2yz-2zx = -20$$

(a,b) satisfies
$$(A) \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}(a,b)=\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}(a,b)=0$$

I have to find all the $(a,b)$ satisfing (A).

---

What I have tried

I have found
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=-\frac{f_x}{f_z}=0$$
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=-\frac{f_y}{f_z}=0$$

In this case
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\frac{x-y-z}{x+y}=0$$
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\frac{-x+2y-z}{x+y}=0$$

So I made an equation
$$-x+2y-z=x-y-z$$
then got$$x=\frac{3}{2}y$$

Is it correct to conclude that all the $(a,b)$ can be expressed with$ \left(
  \begin{array}{c}
    x \\
    y \\
    \end{array}
\right)= t\left(
  \begin{array}{c}
    \frac{3}{2} \\
    1 \\
    \end{array}
\right)$ ?